# Initialise Stack pointer on ATtiny2313

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, avrdude

I am programming an ATtiny2313 using avrdude and a makefile. I believe the stack pointer is not properly initialised, since when I call a function, the program appears to freeze. I found the following assembly code:

```
.include "tn2313def.inc"
ldi r16, low(RAMEND)   ; Main program start 
out SPL,r16      ;Set Stack Pointer to top of RAM
```

which I think might work, but I don't know how I can incorporate it into the c code that I created. ie. do I need to include a special header file or somehow denote that it is assembly and not c. I am relatively new to programming and I would appreciate any help either as to how to implement this code properly or another way of making my current c code initialise a stack pointer.

Thank you in advance.

Stephen

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you've got your makefile configured as to whether the stack pointer will be initialised.  If you're using `gcc` and the normal compile and link options, the linker ensures that some startup code `crtX.o` is also included in your executable.  The linker automatically chooses the correct `crtX.o` file for your processor and compile options.

Amongst other things, the code in the `crtX.o` files will clear the bss segment to be all zeros as required by the C standard, configure your stack pointer and provide interrupt vectors in the correct location for those which have not been overridden.

Remember that the ATTiny2313 only has 128 bytes of SRAM.  This area must be big enough for any initialised data you have in your program and the stack.  Just the process of calling a simple function will use up quite a number of bytes of RAM to save the registers on the stack before calling the function.

So, I'd suggest to do these things:

- Use the standard makefile if one is provided by your compiler, it will ensure that the standard startup code is included and that the stack/RAM is set up correctly before `main()` is called.
- Turn on the linker map and symbol file output and verify that you actually have some space free that can be used for the stack.
- The Atmel IDE has a reasonable simulator, so try running your code in the simulator.  You'll be able to watch stack usage as you are calling the function and location any odd behaviour.
- You may just happen to have a stack overflow (which is why you came to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) right?